# Unable to export as EXE in export release build

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

On Windows XP 32bits, I find it strange that the FB4 **Export Release Build** doesn't have the option to export as EXE in contrast to the one I have in W7 64bit?

Answer (score 0):

I found the option by redownload and reinstall FB4 installer, I suppose either the latest AIR sdk or a new FB4 with SDK 4.1.0 has the option enabled?